# How competitive for those funded PhD positions in Europe?

Tags: europe, research-group

I am based in Canada but want to apply PhD in Europe. I had tried once three years ago for a research group based in a German University. They usually recruit 10-15 PhDs at one time. I was rejected but received letter saying that there were over 1000 people applying for the 10 positions and I ranked top 10%. Of course that was not enough for me to get into the program.

Three years later, I saw another research group, composed of different universities and more interdisciplinary research. The project is funded by EU and seems to have good training structure and good salary. I have a few questions and the application deadline is next week :(

- What is your take on these interdisciplinary research groups vs a
  regular PhD program?
- Considering the intent of this project is to contribute to the EU subject matter, I wonder how competitive I am (Canadian citizen) compare to EU
  citizens? I do speak intermediate French and was educated in various
  continents (including exchange in Sweden).
- Is working experience valued when it comes to these research groups? I have been working for
  governments (provincial and federal level) in the policy shop for the past 6+ years after my master
  degree so my stats/data skill is a bit raw right now.
- Another question I have (a bit related to admission) is that in the
  application package I am supposed to submit a list of recent
  activities, should I mention a government report I did? It is not a
  thesis-style writing but related to the research topic I am applying
  for.

Please feel free to add any advice. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Can you add your field? Is science in the project specifically EU-focused, or is it simply EU-funded?

Comment: Additionally, by "research group composed of different universities", do you mean an ITN/ETN?

Comment: It is EU-focused under ITN.

Comment: Regarding your governemnt report experience, absolutely yes: these european projects requires a large overhead of crap paperwork, including deliverables and milestones and half reports, so your familiarity with gov rep can be useful.

Comment: Thank you! That is good to know!

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to quantitatively say how competitive funded PhD positions are in Europe, but as to your other questions:

> What is your take on these interdisciplinary research groups vs a regular PhD program?

Perhaps this is a field-specific terminology, but an ITN usually consists of multiple different research groups (at different institutions) working under a shared umbrella. This means that if you are accepted, you will still be enrolled at a participating university in their PhD program, *and* get all of the ITN perks (very good salary, budget for stays abroad, workshops). At least in my field, an EU funded PhD position is well-regarded. They are also perceived as more competitive than other positions, but I don't have hard data to back that up.

> Considering the intent of this project is to contribute to the EU
> subject matter, I wonder how competitive I am (Canadian citizen)
> compare to EU citizens? I do speak intermediate French and was
> educated in various continents (including exchange in Sweden).

In principle, your citizenship shouldn't matter for considerations- ITNs try to cast a wide net. But since this program is research-based, the deciding factor should be how well-suited you are to do the research. You'll need to make a case why you specifically want to work on an EU-focused project, what your interest in the EU is, etc... . It might be easier for EU-citizens to make a compelling case for this. That being said, having already lived in the EU could help, if you can connect it to your research.

> Is working experience valued when it comes to these research groups? I
> have been working for governments (provincial and federal level) in
> the policy shop for the past 6+ years after my master degree so my
> stats/data skill is a bit raw right now.

If your work experience relates to the proposed PhD topic, absolutely! Otherwise it's probably not that relevant. But this is also a question of argumentation- I'm not in your field, but I could imagine experience in working in policy to be helpful if the PhD is related to EU policy. You could also argue that this would give you a different perspective on the research topic.

> Another question I have (a bit related to admission) is that in the
> application package I am supposed to submit a list of recent
> activities, should I mention a government report I did? It is not a
> thesis-style writing but related to the research topic I am applying
> for.

I'd recommend including it! While the publication styles (article, book chapter, etc.) vary by field, your future supervisor will want you to produce some form of output- to be blunt, nobody cares about your thesis, but they do care about publishing your work (this used to be an explicit success metric for ETNs/ITNs).

**Miscellaneous advice:**

PhD programs in Europe are very research-focused, which means that the main goal of your application should make the case that you're a strong candidate to do research in "insert topic". Some international mobility can be helpful, mostly to make the case that you aren't going to collapse under the culture shock of leaving Canada. But the key will be to argue that your current experience makes you a good fit to the science of their project. That being said, if your ITN/ETN has some form of applicant pooling - i.e. the option to submit a ranked choice of several different positions, or to be reconsidered as an applicant for other locations if you don't get your original choice - I would strongly recommend that, since the competitiveness between different nodes can vary a lot.

Comment: Thank you for your response! A lot of great points here! Following your suggestion, I just realized that I have another report (from volunteering) to list.